# How to Delete Duplicate Cell Value without Deleting the entire row

Tags: microsoft-excel

Does anyone here know of a faster way of deleting Duplicate Values without deleting other Data in  excel? What I am trying to do is If Customer and Confirmation are the same, delete the duplicate amounts only. Keep the data from the other columns untouched.

[image: Excel table with duplicates]

This is the output I am looking for.

[image: desired Excel table]

Answer (score 0):

A simple way would be to set a helper column somewhere (it doesn't have to be permanent... you could even insert a worksheet for it and delete the worksheet afterwards if you like:  doing this kind of thing means there's absolutely no impact on your actual sheet even if you forget to delete the worksheet later).

In the helper column, place a formula like:

```
=IF( A2&"|"&B2&"|"&C2 = A1&"|"&B1&"|"&C1, "",  C2)
```

which will populate the column with your desired result. Copy that material to the Clipboard and `Paste|Special|Values` overtop your original data in the Table. This will place the desired result... into place. Formatting in the Table will not be affected. Delete the helper column or its material, or even the helper worksheet you inserted to clean up that part.

This is obviously NOT automatic. You will need VBA to do it automatically.

Depending upon your use of the material, a simpler approach than even the above might be of interest.

If you will NOT be using the material in question for anything other than visual uses (so, not drawing upon the column's cells for a formula somewhere else and expecting an actual blank, or taking a sum of or average of the column, that kind of thing:  you just want to look at it), then a simple Conditional Format for the column's cells (starting in the second data row, not the first one) using the above formula in the following version:

```
=A2&"|"&B2&"|"&C2=A1&"|"&B1&"|"&C1
```

and selecting `White` as the text color for cells that are duplicates as defined in your question would make the duplicates "disappear" accomplishing the purely visual goal.

There is no good way, outside of VBA, to combine that with, say `Find and Replace` as `FAR` looks at "real" formatting, not Conditional Formats.

So, simple ways that could do your required need, but not automatic ways. You'd have to choose when to do them and then do them. Or have users do them... which leads into the Land of Problems, of course.

VBA may be what you want to ask about, perhaps in a new Question. Even users can (usually) manage to click on a button labelled "Remove Duplicates" and might even find it fun to "watch the magic" as the values suddenly pop out of existence.